# How Admin can logout other users?

Tags: 6, users

The users can logout visinting my-site.com/logout by themselves
But is there any way Admin can logout other users?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you go to `admin/user/user`, you can *block* the user, which will cause them to be logged out.  After that, if you want them to be able to login again, you can just immediately *unblock* them.  Also, if you as an admin change a user's password, they will be logged out and will have to use this new password to log back in.

If you want to get fancy, you could do something like this in a custom module as well:

```
function YOURMODULE_user_operations($form_state = array()) {

  $operations = array(
    'logout' => array(
      'label' => t('Logout the selected users'),
      'callback' => 'YOURMODULE_user_operations_logout',
    ),
  );

  return $operations;

}

function YOURMODULE_user_operations_logout($accounts) {
  foreach ($accounts as $uid) {
    sess_destroy_uid($uid);
  }
}
```

which would add a "Logout the selected users" option to that menu as well.

Comment: quite welcome, I added some quick off the cuff fanciness to the answer as well.

Comment: I love learning about hooks I have never used.  What a simple solution to a common problem.

Comment: Two quick notes about this.  `sess_destroy_uid` is for Drupal 6.  Use `drupal_session_destroy_uid` for Drupal 7.  This won't work with Administration Views in Drupal 7 (haven't tested 6), which use VBO.  VBO removed hook_user_operations, so you have to use an action instead.